# How to extract specific character from a cell into separate column? (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have some texts which varies in a database. I need to:

1. Check if the cell contains specific character like: 20/1, 30/1, 200D, etc.
2. Need to extract these specific characters (there may be many) into separate individual column.
   e:g: FLD270-20/1+75D+2X200D - Column1: 20/1 , Column2: 75D, Column3: 200D, etc.

Any Help Appreciate.

I need to be able to output respective value from row AU4:BO4

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot seems to be showing the position of the substring; but your question is asking to return the actual substring if present.  What do you really want?  And what does "*output respective value from row AU4:BO4*" mean?  Also, please show the attempts you've made to solve your problem.  And the desired and expected results. That may also help to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** through **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("20/1",A1)),"20/1","")
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("30/1",A1)),"30/1","")
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("200D",A1)),"200D","")
```

basicly one formula for each specific pattern

Then copy **B1** through **D1** *(or as many columns as you need)* downward.

[image]